# Updating Bound LINQ to Entities DataSource

Tags: c#, mysql, linq, entity-framework

OK, so I am learning the Entity Framework and LINQ to connect to a remote MySQL database using the MySQL ADO .NET Connector.

I have set up my Entity Data Model previously. Now, I'll use a lambda expression to grab a list of all the van objects from the data store and bind the results to a grid view:

```
dataEntities db = new dataEntities();

var vans = from v in db.vans
   select v;

gridControl1.DataSource = vans;
```

That works very well. However, when the data in the remote store changes, I'd like to update the grid view without having to execute the above code again. What would be the correct way to handle this? I realize that I would move the `db` object to a module or other global scope, but how would I update the `vans` object in a later event, say a button press?

Comment: sorry - you want to get the latest data from the db without executing the query again, or you simply want to move the lambda query to a place where you can call it again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to do something equal to thess articles - http://www.devart.com/linqconnect/docs/ASPNetBinding.html or http://www.devart.com/linqconnect/docs/WinFormsBinding.html.